# How to Use CONTAINS keyword in Sqlite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, search

what i am trying to use is that i want to select cities from my LocationByCity table in sqlite database each time As user inters search word in a search box,
for example if user enters F i want all the CityNames Starting From F ,so how can i do that?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd have to check up, but I believe you want to use the LIKE keyword.

Syntax somthing along the lines of:

```
Select Fieldname From Tablename where fieldname LIKE ('%$myvar%');
```

where the % signs are wildcard characters.

Not sure if sqlite has fulltext indexing so you should be aware that can get very slow depending on how many rows you have in the table.